# React recompiling when I make a change instead of when I save

Tags: reactjs

It used to only recompile when I saved the file, now it's recompiling every time I make a change. It's functioning exactly like codesandbox pretty much. Did I edit something by accident?

Comment: can you provide more information? are you using create-react-app? or configured nodemon?

Comment: What IDE are you using? How would the react compiler which reads files from disk use a filecontent which isn't saved to disk?

Comment: oh shit sorry. Yeah, i'm using create-react-app in visual studio code

Answer (score 2):

**Go to File Menu and uncheck Auto Save :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some extensions installed in your visual studio code is autosaving the changes.Check installed extensions and try again later.